# Initializing member variables in member functions

Tags: c++

So I'm now implementing a c++ program and the thing is that I don't know whether the context below is possible or not.

```
class Foo{
     private:
          int a;
       public:
          Foo(int _a) : a(_a){

           }   

          void func(int _a) : a(_a){
              //implementation shows here
         }   
 };
```

As you can see here, there are member function which initializes a member variable in a manner like a constructor do. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not possible and doesn't make much sense: member initialisation is only performed on *construction*.

In the function `func`, you're setting the member variable to something else, and *assignment* does that job perfectly well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Windforces, if this answers your question. Accept it to mark it as the solution for future reference to readers.

Comment: I cannot because I accepted another answer for another question about 10 minutes ago. So I need 10 minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba, the only case I could think of where this requirement "makes sense" is in pre-C++11 where you can't call one constructor from another. You normally need an `init` function, which actually initializes by assignment.

Answer (score 3):

No. Initialization lists can only be used with constructors.

`func` would have to look like this.

```
      void func(int _a) {
         a = _a; 
          //implementation shows here
     }
```

Obviously `func` can't initialise references, and the `Foo` constructor will be called before `func` can ever run...